# Sql Table join query

Tags: c#

I have 3 tables in sql

1. ProductMaster with column ProductName
2. PurchaseData with column ProductName and Quantity
3. SaleData with column ProductName and Quantity

Please guide me to write query for table join to get the result as under

```
PRODUCT1   10    5     5
PRODUCT2   10    0     10
PRODUCT3   10    5     5
```

Comment: 1. You have Quantity from PurchaseData table, and Quantity from SaleData Table, your expected result contains 3 quantities (eg for PRODUCT1 : 10 5 and 5). From where the third quantity is coming ?
<br/>
2. Do you want your result on one row instead of 3 rows ?

Comment: PURCHASE - SALE = CLOSING STOCK

Comment: I WANT A TABLE WITH COLUMN  1)PRODUCTNAME , 2)PURCHASE QTY, 3) SALEQTY 4)CLOSING STOCK QTY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need anymore ProductMaster Table, because all information you need are in PURCHASEDATA and SALEDATA

```
SELECT P.[ProductName] as ProductName, P.PurchaseQty, S.SalteQTY, P.purchaseQTY-S.SalteQTY as ClosingQty

  FROM [PURCHASEDATA] P LEFT OUTER JOIN [SALEDATA] S ON P.ProductName=S.ProductName
```

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` allows you to get data even if Productname not existing in your SALEDATA table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start with something like this:

```
SELECT [ProductMaster].[ProductName]
    ,[PurchaseData].[Quantity]  AS [PurchasedQuantity]
    ,[SaleData].[Quantity]      AS [SoldQuantity]
    ,[PurchaseData].[Quantity] 
        - [SaleData].[Quantity] AS [ClosingStock]
  FROM [ProductMaster]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [PurchaseData]
        ON [ProductMaster].[ProductName] = [PurchaseData].[ProductName]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [SaleData]
        ON [ProductMaster].[ProductName] = [SaleData].[ProductName]
```

The idea is to have the master table and join the two dependent tables to the master with an INNER JOIN on the ProductName field.

Comment: Thanks you soo much.......its working but one miner issue is here.The product which is only purchase but not sold out that product is not showing in the table.....

Comment: So use a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN